# Return overlapping date records in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I used the following query to fetch the overlapping records in SQL:

```
SELECT QUOTE_ID,FUNCTION_ID,FUNCTION_DT,FUNC_SPACE_ID,FN_START_TIME,FN_END_TIME,DATE_AUTH_LEVEL
FROM R_13_ALL_RESERVED A 
WHERE 
    A.FUNC_SPACE_ID = '401-ZFU-52' 
AND A.FUNCTION_DT = TO_DATE('09/03/2015','MM/DD/YYYY')
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
             FROM R_13_ALL_RESERVED B
             WHERE A.PROPERTY = B.PROPERTY
               AND A.FUNCTION_DT = B.FUNCTION_DT 
               AND A.FUNCTION_ID <> B.FUNCTION_ID
               AND ( (    A.FN_START_TIME > B.FN_START_TIME 
                      AND A.FN_START_TIME < B.FN_END_TIME) 
                  OR (    B.FN_START_TIME > A.FN_START_TIME 
                      AND B.FN_START_TIME < A.FN_END_TIME)
                  OR (    A.FN_START_TIME = B.FN_START_TIME 
                      AND A.FN_END_TIME = B.FN_END_TIME)
                   )
           )
```

But eventhough the dates are not overlapping it still returns the records as overlapping.

I am missing some thing here?

Also if the date records overlap, I need to compare the count of `function_id` records with `DATE_AUTH_LEVEL`, if 2 `function_id` records overlap and the count of `function_id` would be 2 and `DATE_AUTH_LEVEL` is 1, such record should in the result set.

Please find the data set in SQLFiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95874/1

**Desired Output :** The SQL should return overlapping FN_START_TIME and FN_END_TIME for a function_space_id and it's  function_dt

In the provided example, row **5 and 6 overlap** for the function space id '401-ZFU-12' and function_dt 'August, 15 2015' and all others are not overlapping

Comment: Hello next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't see why it would show false overlaps, but the best check for overlaps is simply `(a.start_time < b.end_time and b.start_time < a.end_time)` - see [this explanation](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/sql-overlap-test.html)

Comment: You should provide both, sample data and desire output

Comment: I'm facing some difficulties with SQL fiddle, I shall try to provide the details ASAP

Comment: @user2999377 you create a fiddle for MySql instead of Oracle try [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cb8f9) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest predicate (where clause condition) for detecting the overlap of two ranges is to compare the start of the first range with the end of the 2nd range, and the start of the 2nd range with the end of the first range:

```
WHERE R1.Start_Date <= R2.End_Date
  AND R2.Start_Date <= R1.End_Date
```

As you can see each of the two inequalities looks at a start and end value from separate records (R1 and R2 and then R2 and R1 respectively) all that remains is to add the conditions that will correlate the records, and also ensure that you aren't comparing a row to itself So if you want to find all Common_IDs that have Distinct_IDs with over lapping date ranges:

```
select *
  from Your_Table R1
 where exists (select 1 from Your_Table R2
                where R1.Common_ID = R2.Common_ID
                  and R1.Distinct_ID <> R2.Distinct_ID
                  and R1.Start_Date <= R2.End_Date
                  and R2.Start_Date <= R1.End_Date)
```

If there is no Distinct_ID to use, you can use `R1.rowid <> R2.rowid` in place of `R1.Distinct_ID <> R2.Distinct_ID`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to troubleshooting the issue on your end.

My first suspicion is that the results of your `exists` clause are too broad and thus returning rows for every record matching in the outer clause unexpectedly.  Likely there are rows that do not fall on the desired date or spaceid that share one component of their interval with your inner criteria.

- Inspect the results of the inner `select` statement (the one within the `exists` clause) for an example row, exchanging all the **'A'** aliased values with actual values from one of the rows returned you did not expect to receive.
- Additionally, you can inspect what I think would be a `semi join` in the execution profile to see what the join criteria are.  If you expect it to be filtered by a constant for **'FUNC_SPACE_ID'** of **'401-ZFU-52'**, you will discover that it is not.